# how to define graphical bounds of abline linear regression in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I am trying to truncate the ends of an abline, which is actually just a linear regression of my data.

```
fit1=lm(logy~logx)

> fit1

Call:
lm(formula = logy ~ logx)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         logx  
     -5.339       -2.115
```

Where logx is `log10(x[1:365]` transformed. logy follows the same code. When I plot with `abline(fit1,col="red")`, I get the line I wanted, but the line extends past the bounds I have originally set `[1:365]`. I have tried `par=xpd` and that doesn't reduce the line to the limits I want. I've played around with `segments()` to no avail. Maybe it is a `line()` argument?

edit
Here is the new solution:

```
#the following vectors x and y store our data that we want to plot
x<-(1:10)
y<-(10:1)
plot(x,y,type="l",log="xy")
#we want to do a linear regression on our log10 transformed data and add the line to the plot
logy=log10(y[3:8])
logx=log10(x[3:8])
fit1=lm(logy~logx)
#finally, we want the regression line to only seem like it applies over the range from 3 to 8
clip(3,8,8,3)
abline(fit1,col="red")
```

what this yields is a plot with a line that (now, does not) extends past 3 to 8 on our x-axis. I only want the regression line to display from x=3 to x=8, following the same slope.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: you might have to use `segment()` and evalute at x = 3 and x = 8

Comment: I tried playing with `segment()` and I don't think I am understanding the syntax in the R help database. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `clip` the drawing area. I can not use your data as your example is not reproducible, but here is an illustration:

```
> plot(1,1,type='n',xlim=c(0,400), ylim=c(0,10))
> clip(1,365,0,10)
> abline(h=5,col='red')
```

Results in a line that is bounded inside the box of coordinates `x0=1,x1=365,y0=0,y1=10`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The key here for me was to make sure that i started a device `png(filename="test")` and put `clip()` as it's own argument after everything I didn't want clipped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `segments()`

For example:

```
segments(x0=3, # Value from x (initial)
         x1=8, # Value to x (final)
         y0=5, # Value from y (initial)
         y1=5, # Value to y (final)
         col='red')
```